# Display list in recyclerView, sorted as per Date from JSON using retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, android-recyclerview

So, I am making an app where I need to show a transaction lists, where i get the date and time of transaction as follows

```
 {
        "transaction_id": "7",
        "transaction_date": "2018-06-06 04:46:01.0",
        "amount": "499.50",
        "user_id": "2",
        "currency": "MXN",
        "associate_id": "2",
        "associate": {
            "is_active": "N",
            "associate_type": "asd",
            "name": "asd",
            "created_date": "12-Feb-2018 07:32:12 AM",
            "associate_id": "2",
            "url": null,
            "last_update_date": "12-Feb-2018 07:32:12 AM"
        },
        "card_id": "1",
        "card": null
    }
```

I am using recyclerView to populate, now I want to display the list as follows;

[image: Example BluePrint]

So, can somebody help me with the process of making this happen?

Comment: Have a look at the tutorial below for a step-by-step introduction on how to use recycler views.
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a **Model class** for your response which implements [Comparable interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

This class will override **compareTo** method which will gonna sort the transaction based on the **transaction_date**.

**Model class**

```
public class Transactions implements Comparable<Transactions> {

    @SerializedName("transaction_id")
    public String transactionId;

    @SerializedName("transaction_date")
    public String transactionDate;

    @SerializedName("amount")
    public String amount;

    @SerializedName("user_id")
    public String userId;

    @SerializedName("currency")
    public String currency;

    @SerializedName("associate_id")
    public String associateId;

    @SerializedName("associate")
    public Associate associate;

    @SerializedName("card_id")
    public String cardId;

    @SerializedName("card")
    public Object card;

    public class Associate {

        @SerializedName("is_active")
        public String isActive;

        @SerializedName("associate_type")
        public String associateType;

        @SerializedName("name")
        public String name;

        @SerializedName("created_date")
        public String createdDate;

        @SerializedName("associate_id")
        public String associateId;

        @SerializedName("url")
        public Object url;

        @SerializedName("last_update_date")
        public String lastUpdateDate;

    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Transactions transaction) {
        return new Date(this.transactionDate).compareTo(new Date(transaction.transactionDate));
    }
}
```

Before passing the data to Adapter class, sort the list using [Collection framework API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))

```
ArrayList<Transactions> transactionList = new ArrayList<Transactions>();  

Collections.sort(transactionList);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the prompt suggestion, I will try to apply it.

Comment: I hope you understood the solution. Feel free to write back in case of any doubt